# How can I convert this PIVOT sql to CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, case

I want to convert this PIVOT to CASE WHEN since I read that PIVOT is slow against a large database.
Is it possible?
I tried converting it BUT failed, it is displaying all the cmdocumentdefn.code COUNT which is 50. I want to count the code by weekday i.e.

```
MON  TUE  WED .... SUN
8     2    4        1
```

**The query is:**

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT 
        cmdocumentdefn.code, cmdocumentdefn.description 'description',
        CASE DatePart(weekday,cmrevisionaddress.issueddate)
        WHEN 1 THEN 'SUN'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'MON'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'TUE' 
        WHEN 4 THEN 'WED'
        WHEN 5 THEN 'THU'
        WHEN 6 THEN 'FRI'
        WHEN 7 THEN 'SAT'
        END  'dayx'    
    FROM cmdocumentdefn
        INNER JOIN
        cmdocument
        ON cmdocumentdefn.cmdocumentdefn = cmdocument.cmdocumentdefn
        INNER JOIN cmrevisionaddress
        ON cmdocument.cmdocument = cmrevisionaddress.cmdocument WHERE cmdocumentdefn.code = 'AF') x
    PIVOT(COUNT(dayx) FOR dayx IN([MON],[TUE],[WED],[THU],[FRI],[SAT],[SUN])) pvt
```

Comment: SELECT 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN (CASE DatePart(weekday,cmrevisionaddress.issueddate)
    WHEN 1 THEN 'SUN'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'MON'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'TUE' 
    WHEN 4 THEN 'WED'
    WHEN 5 THEN 'THU'
    WHEN 6 THEN 'FRI'
    WHEN 7 THEN 'SAT'
    END) = 'MON' THEN 'MON' ELSE '' END) AS MON ...

I am not getting the correct COUNT, it is not counting per weekday

Comment: Could you please provide example data and expected result?

Comment: headers of MON, TUE, WED
and underneath it are count. CODE DESCRIPTION before the count.

I hope you get what I'm saying. I can't format my answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @data TABLE (ID int, Code nvarchar(10), Description nvarchar(100), DocDate datetime) 
INSERT INTO @data VALUES(1, 'FA', 'lorem ipsum 1', '2021-07-05')
INSERT INTO @data VALUES(2, 'FA', 'lorem ipsum 2', '2021-07-05')
INSERT INTO @data VALUES(3, 'FA', 'lorem ipsum 3', '2021-07-05')
INSERT INTO @data VALUES(4, 'FA', 'lorem ipsum 4', '2021-07-05')
INSERT INTO @data VALUES(5, 'SH', 'lorem ipsum 5', '2021-08-31')
INSERT INTO @data VALUES(6, 'SH', 'lorem ipsum 6', '2021-08-31')
INSERT INTO @data VALUES(7, 'SH', 'lorem ipsum 7', '2021-08-31')
INSERT INTO @data VALUES(8, 'AG', 'lorem ipsum 8', '2021-09-15')
INSERT INTO @data VALUES(9, 'AG', 'lorem ipsum 9', '2021-09-15')
INSERT INTO @data VALUES(10, 'XX', 'lorem ipsum 10', '2021-10-21')


SELECT Code, Description, 
        IIF(DATEPART(weekday, DocDate) = 1, 1, 0) AS SUN,
        IIF(DATEPART(weekday, DocDate) = 2, 1, 0) AS MON,
        IIF(DATEPART(weekday, DocDate) = 3, 1, 0) AS TUE,
        IIF(DATEPART(weekday, DocDate) = 4, 1, 0) AS WED,
        IIF(DATEPART(weekday, DocDate) = 5, 1, 0) AS THU,
        IIF(DATEPART(weekday, DocDate) = 6, 1, 0) AS FRI,
        IIF(DATEPART(weekday, DocDate) = 7, 1, 0) AS SAT
FROM @data
```

I took the 1st 10 rows of the example data. This is the result:
[image]

If you want the sum for each `code` then this is the query:

```
SELECT Code,  
        SUM(IIF(DATEPART(weekday, DocDate) = 1, 1, 0)) AS SUN,
        SUM(IIF(DATEPART(weekday, DocDate) = 2, 1, 0)) AS MON,
        SUM(IIF(DATEPART(weekday, DocDate) = 3, 1, 0)) AS TUE,
        SUM(IIF(DATEPART(weekday, DocDate) = 4, 1, 0)) AS WED,
        SUM(IIF(DATEPART(weekday, DocDate) = 5, 1, 0)) AS THU,
        SUM(IIF(DATEPART(weekday, DocDate) = 6, 1, 0)) AS FRI,
        SUM(IIF(DATEPART(weekday, DocDate) = 7, 1, 0)) AS SAT
FROM @data
GROUP BY Code
```

And the result:
[image]

Comment: I am not getting the output I want. I will try to rewrite the query and see what I get.
Thanks for the time. Highly appreciate it!

Comment: @LeonardoVicenteRapirap Could you provide some sample data with the expected result? It would be easier to come up with the solution because the question is not well explained.

Comment: I cannot create a sample table in db fiddle coz I don't have an account, I instead captured the table with data and the target output. [paste.pics/1b2cfa33158a663b540f95c87c37995e - table] and [paste.pics/eab5c61b16a4d94673e1faa41a58872e - target output]

Comment: @LeonardoVicenteRapirap I edited my original answer to fit with the newly provided example data and expected result.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I'm singing "Just what I'm looking for". This is really what I'm looking for. I highly appreciate it! You're great!!!

Comment: may I ask? what does 1 and 0 represent? 
SUM(IIF(DATEPART(weekday, DocDate) = 7, 1, 0))

Comment: @LeonardoVicenteRapirap This is the result of IIF condition. IIF is just a neat way to write a `CASE WHEN`, read about it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively use the logic which contains conditional aggregation with `SUM()` such as

```
WITH d AS -- in order to generate fixed integers from 1 to 7 for the day of a week 
(
 SELECT 1 AS day_num
 UNION ALL
 SELECT day_num+1 FROM d WHERE day_num+1<=7
), cra AS
(
 SELECT DatePart(weekday, issueddate) AS day
   FROM d
   LEFT JOIN cmrevisionaddress
     ON DatePart(weekday, issueddate) = day_num
)
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN day=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MON,
       SUM(CASE WHEN day=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TUE,
       SUM(CASE WHEN day=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS WED,
       SUM(CASE WHEN day=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS THU,
       SUM(CASE WHEN day=6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FRI,
       SUM(CASE WHEN day=7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SAT,
       SUM(CASE WHEN day=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SUN
  FROM cmdocumentdefn AS cdd
  JOIN cmdocument AS cd
    ON cdd.cmdocumentdefn = cd.cmdocumentdefn
  JOIN cra
    ON cd.cmdocument = cra.cmdocument
 WHERE cdd.code = 'AF'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ae9825c2ba669a96991ccb9eb097e765)</kbd>

Comment: I think those joins are incorrect. You need `FROM d LEFT JOIN cmrevisionaddress AS cra JOIN cmdocument AS cd ON ... ON ON DatePart(weekday, issueddate) = day_num` Note how the inner join is nested inside the left join

Comment: I tried your solution BUT I am not getting what I want. 
Thank you for the time spent on this. Much appreciated!

Comment: Hi @LeonardoVicenteRapirap you're welcome. I think sharing some DDL to represent creation of tables, and just a few rows of sample data would help to reproduce the problem well.

Comment: I cannot create a sample table in db fiddle coz I don't have an account, I instead captured the table with  data and the target output. [https://paste.pics/1b2cfa33158a663b540f95c87c37995e - table] and [https://paste.pics/eab5c61b16a4d94673e1faa41a58872e - target output]